# this.$el.html vs this.$el.append

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

Is there a different between this.$el.html and this.$el.append when rendering templates?  I'm totally new to js, backbone, etc.  In the current project I'm working on, I see stuff like

```
this.$el.append(Project.Templates["template-library"](this.model))
```

in the outer view.  In this case, this template is for a modal view.  Then say the modal view has a row for each item to show in the modal view.  Then for each of those rows, the template gets rendered like this:

```
this.$el.html(this.template({ libraries: libraries.toJSON() }));
```

Is there any difference between the two?  And why `append()` should be used in certain situations, and `html()` in the other.

Comment: I guess there is one (html) that just replace the content with the argument you got and the other (append) add the argument at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it really comes down to how you use your views' `render` method.

Some people like to use `render` as an extension of `initialize`, in that they only use it once, when the view first appears on the page, and often call it from `initialize`.  With this style, you can safely use `append` without worrying about accidentally adding elements twice, because the render won't get run twice.

Alternatively you can design `render` to be used over and over again, whenever the view's element needs to change in some way.  Backbone supports this style well, eg. `this.model.on('change', this.render, this);`.  For this style, `append` would be annoying, as you'd constantly have to check whether elements already exist before `append`-ing them.  Instead `html` makes more sense, because it wipes out whatever was there before.

Answer (score 1):

With [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) a new element will be inserted into the `$el`, while [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) will change the content of the `$el`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.append()` will allow you to add or append something to already existing objects. Rather using `.html()`, it will change the entire object to new one.